# React MUI Issue - Clicking on InputAdornment doesn't open the Popup

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using the Autocomplete component as in the [country example](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#country-select), but decorated with the *InputAdornment* component in order to show the flag of the select country.

Here the working code:

[image: Edit CountrySelect Material Demo (forked)]

**The problem**: after picking a country, if the user clicks *exactly* on the flag, country's name is selected. And, if the user clicks on the remaining part of the Autocomplete, the Popper is showing up (as expected and that's totally ok).

Current behaviour:

[image]

MY GOAL: I'd like to **open the Autocomplete Popper even when clicking on the flag.**

Expected behaviour:

[image]

I tried to use the option *disablePointerEvents* in the InputAdornment parameters, but nothing changed.
I tried the same on a pure Textfield MUI component and it worked, so it maybe it is something related to Autocomplete only.

Is there a workaround for this issue?

Same issue [here](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/16665#issuecomment-647322752)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to control the `open` state of the `Autocomplete` using the `open`, `onOpen`, and `onClose` props and then add an `onClick` (instead of `disablePointerEvents`) to the `InputAdornment` to open the `Autocomplete`.

Here is a working example based on your sandbox:

```
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";
import InputAdornment from "@mui/material/InputAdornment";

export default function CountrySelect() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="country-select-demo"
      value={value}
      onChange={(event, newValue) => {
        setValue(newValue);
      }}
      sx={{ width: 300 }}
      options={countries}
      autoHighlight
      open={open}
      onOpen={() => setOpen(true)}
      onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
      renderOption={(props, option) => (
        <Box
          component="li"
          sx={{ "& > img": { mr: 2, flexShrink: 0 } }}
          {...props}
        >
          <img
            loading="lazy"
            width="20"
            src={`https://flagcdn.com/w20/${option.code.toLowerCase()}.png`}
            srcSet={`https://flagcdn.com/w40/${option.code.toLowerCase()}.png 2x`}
            alt=""
          />
          {option.label} ({option.code}) +{option.phone}
        </Box>
      )}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          label="Choose a country"
          inputProps={{
            ...params.inputProps,
            autoComplete: "new-password" // disable autocomplete and autofill
          }}
          InputProps={{
            ...params.InputProps,
            startAdornment: value ? (
              <InputAdornment position="start" onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>
                <img
                  loading="lazy"
                  width="48"
                  src={`https://flagcdn.com/w20/${value.code.toLowerCase()}.png`}
                  srcSet={`https://flagcdn.com/w40/${value.code.toLowerCase()}.png 2x`}
                  alt=""
                />
              </InputAdornment>
            ) : null
          }}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

[image: Edit CountrySelect Material Demo (forked)]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Actually I also solved with the property "openOnFocus".

Comment: `openOnFocus` doesn't entirely fix the problem because it still won't open if you click on the flag when the Autocomplete already has focus. For instance, if you click in the input (opening the popper) and select a country, the popper will close and the Autocomplete still has focus. If you now click the flag of the selected country, the popper will not open.